# Cross-browser enabling/disabling mouse scroll wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have 2 button: "disable_scroll" and "enable_scroll" for enabling/disabling mouse scroll.
Disabling scroll works well:

```
 var cancelscroll = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
 };

  $("#disable_scroll").on("click", function () {
       if ("onmousewheel" in document) { // for browser except FF
            document.onmousewheel = cancelscroll;
       } else { // for  FF
            document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', cancelscroll);
       }
  });
```

but when I want to enable mouse scroll, I have problems in Firefox. In Firefox, the mouse scroll won't turn on (in other browsers, this code works well). Please can anyone help locate the error?

```
 $("#enable_scroll").on("click", function () {
            if ("onmousewheel" in document) { // for brouzers except FF
                document.onmousewheel = function(e){};
            } else { // for  FF
                document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){});
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works everywhere: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js

You use it like this:

```
$('#test3')
                .hover(function() { log('#test3: mouseover'); }, function() { log('#test3: mouseout'); })
                .mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
                    log('#test3: I should not have been logged');
                })
                .unmousewheel();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is source jquery mousewheel plugin yes? i dot see here, how to enable/disable mouse scroll functionalitty.
I want make only enabling/disabling mouse scroll.